# Python Showing ModuleNotFoundError despite me having installed openpyxl

Tags: python, import, terminal, module, openpyxl

So I was making a python module and wanted to use the openpyxl module.
I went to the Terminal and typed in pip install openpyxl.
It said it had installed openpyxl.
Then I started typing in the code and wrote import openpyxl but it said that ModuleNotFoundError
What do I do?

Comment: How are you executing your code? From the terminal or are you using Pycharm?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add the output of both `pip freeze` and `python3 --version`?